# Print content just one inside a loop for

Tags: php, list, codeigniter, for-loop, view

I need to show some Information when a condition is true, but the problem is that the condition is true many times. I think to do an `array()` but I do not know how to do it with this.

**My View**

```
<?php
$prev_state = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
$state = $list[$i]['state'];
$name = $list[$i]['name'];
   if($prev_state != $state ){
      if($state == '3'){
        echo 'Header A';
       }//state = 3 
   else {
      echo 'Headear B';
    }
  }// if
  $prev_state = $state; 
?>
<div>
Name: <?php echo $name; ?>
</div>
<?php
}// for loop
?>
```

In my `$list` I have many records, and in the variable `prev_state` always change,

1. has  ' '
2. has 3
3. has 1
4. has 3 again, but how the previous has **1** print again `Header A`, and I do not want that.

The other thing, I want that headers(A and B) shows the first time that the condition is true. 
**Example:**

```
**Header A**
 - Marcus (this has state = 3)
 - Lia    (this has state = 3)

**Header B** 
 - Robert (this has state = 1)
 - Loise  (this has state = 3)
 - Bob    (this has state = 1)
 - Fer    (this has state = 3)
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is about your syntax. Your syntax is the problem. I used your code and rewrited a new one, it is ok.

```
<?php
    $prev_state = '';
    $list = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'marcus',
            'state' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'lia',
            'state' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'robert',
            'state' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'loise',
            'state' => 3
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'bob',
            'state' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'fer',
            'state' => 3
        )
    );
    $cont = count($list);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++)
    {
        $state = $list[$i]['state'];
        $name = $list[$i]['name'];
        if($prev_state != $state )
        {
            if($state == '3')
            {
                echo 'Header A';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Headear B';
            }
        }
        $prev_state = $state; 
        echo '<div> Name: ' . $name .'</div>';
    }
?>
```

I think because you close tag like that is the problem. I tested and the result is ok.

```
Header A
Name: marcus
Name: lia
Headear B
Name: robert
Header A
Name: loise
Headear B
Name: bob
Header A
Name: fer
```